# how to write this query in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

how to write this query in sql :
For every player that has played more than two games, list the player name, total amount of winnings and number of games played for each player". The result should be sorted by the winnings in descending order.

and i have in player table these attributes:
playerId,playerName,age
and in games table these attrubites:
gameId,playerId,results note the results attrubie is filled either by (first or second or third or,..,or no show) the winner is the one who has the result= first

this is my weak query i didn't got the right answer ,but that all what i can do . any idea

```
select playerName,count(*),count(*)
 from games,player
 where games.playerId=player.playerId
 group by games.results
```

Comment: I don't see a column related to winnings.

Comment: If you provide a mockup of the table and the result set that you would like to see we might be able to better help you.

Comment: ok the results as follow : playerId-how many time he win the game-how many time he plaied as simple as i state :)

Comment: You are still not stating it very well. There are four answers to the OP by users with 10k+ average rep and no one is understanding your needs. Please provide a table data and result mockup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try this (pretty much as you said it in English...
(if "winnings" is amount won in the game), then:

```
  Select playerName, count(*) Games,  -- Number of game records per player
      Sum(g.Winnings) Winnings        -- Sum of a Winnings attribute (dollars ??)
  from player p Join Games g          -- from the two tables
    On g.PlayerId = p.PlayerId        -- connected using PlayerId
  Group by p.playerName               -- Output in one row per Player
  Having Count(*) > 2                 -- only show players w/more than 2 games
  Order By Sum(g.Winnings)            -- sort the rows based on Player Winnings
```

if by "Winnings" you mean the number of games won, then...

```
  Select playerName, Count(*) Games, -- Number of game records per player
      Sum(Case g.WonTheGame          -- or whatever attribute is used
          When 'Y' Then 1            -- to specify that player won
          Else 0 End) Wins           -- Output in one row per Player
  From player p Join Games g         -- from the two tables
    On g.PlayerId = p.PlayerId       -- connected using PlayerId
  Group by p.playerName              -- Output in one row per Player
  Having Count(*) > 2                -- only show players w/more than 2 games
  Order By Sum(Case g.WonTheGame     -- Sort by Number of games Won
          When 'Y' Then 1 
          Else 0 End)
```

Comment: could you please explain what you write

Comment: ok the results as follow : playerId-how many time he win the game-how many time he plaied as simple as i state

Answer (score 3):

You want to look into [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) in conjunction with `COUNT`.  Something like this would probably do (untested):

```
SELECT
   p.playerName
   ,COUNT(g.*)
   ,SUM(g.Winnings)  -- you didn't name this column
FROM
   games g
   INNER JOIN ON g.playerId = p.playerId
WHERE
   g.results = 1     -- whatever indicates this player was the winner
GROUP BY
   p.playerName
HAVING
   COUNT(g.*) > 2
```

Comment: but there is no column winnings only i have the results such as first and player id

Comment: Then what do you mean by "sort by winnings"?  Sort by the number of games won?  If so, drop the `SUM` and throw an `ORDER BY` with the `COUNT` clause in it (I can edit that in if you confirm this is the case)

Comment: but you can retreive the winer by going over all the rows and see who has "first" in result col then take each player and then count how many he has first in result and this is a problem for me. any way i like your answer but if you consider what i said this will be helpfull :)

Comment: those who has the largest number of results=first

Comment: ok the results as follow : playerId-how many time he win the game-how many time he plaied as simple as i state

Comment: @Lenord that'll probably require a subquery, but without more information about the problem (more information about the schema), it's tough to help with the proper query

Answer (score 0):

it's tough to glean exactly what you need from your question but try something like this:

```
select playerName, count(*)
 from games g
 join player p ON g.playerId = p.playerId
 group by playerName
 having count(*) > 2
 order by games.results DESC
```

Comment: this will returns only player name ,but ineed how many he wins and the total number of games he played

Comment: ok the results as follow : playerId-how many time he win the game-how many time he plaied as simple as i state

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT playerName, COUNT(g.PlayerID) as NumberOfPlays
 FROM games g ,player p 
 WHERE g.playerId=p.playerId 
 GROUP BY g.PlayerID
 HAVING COUNT(g.PlayerID) > 1
 ORDER BY g.results DESC
```

SELECT - the data you want to display 
FROM - the tables
WHERE - both IDs match each other
GROUP BY - Games PlayerID, so all the counts are correct
HAVING - Make sure they played more then one game
ORDER BY - Order the results the way you want them.

Comment: ok the results as follow : playerId-how many time he win the game-how many time he plaied as simple as i state

Answer (score 0):

```
select
playerName,
sum(if(games.result = 'first',1,0)) as wins,
count(*) as gamesPlayed
from player
join games on games.playerId = player.playerId
group by games.results
having count(*) > 2
order by count(*) desc;
```